# clang++ error on <experimental/any>

Tags: c++, clang

I get an error when compile code containing `<experimental/any>`.

Code in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <experimental/any>
int main() { }
```

Compile this (clang version is 3.9):

```
clang++ main.cpp -o main -std=c++1z
```

Error after the compiling:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/experimental/any:364:34: error: 
      no template named '__any_caster'; did you mean 'any_cast'?
        return static_cast<_ValueType*>(__any_caster<_ValueType>(__any));
                                        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/experimental/any:361:30: note: 
      'any_cast' declared here
    inline const _ValueType* any_cast(const any* __any) noexcept
                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/experimental/any:372:34: error: 
      no template named '__any_caster'; did you mean 'any_cast'?
        return static_cast<_ValueType*>(__any_caster<_ValueType>(__any));
                                        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/experimental/any:369:24: note: 
      'any_cast' declared here
    inline _ValueType* any_cast(any* __any) noexcept
                       ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: You could try with libc++. Perhaps there's an incompatibility with Clang in libstdc++'s new header.

Comment: There's a [manual page](http://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html) for that. You can pass `-stdlib=libc++`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352592/clang-error-on-experimental-any#comment66034911_39352592):

> You could try with libc++. Perhaps there's an incompatibility with Clang in libstdc++'s new header.

This turns out to be true. Clang 3.9 is still experimental, and so it uses experimental headers, including a experimental C++ standard library. By default, it is provided by GCC, and so an incompatibility occurs between the GCC implementation and the Clang implementation.