# How to compile #include <experimental/any> for clang on OSX

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++, c++17, llvm-clang

I am trying to get the `#include <experimental/any>` to compile in my C++ program on clang `OSX`

```
// test.cpp
#include <experimental/any>

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Tried following commands/options as learnt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352592/clang-error-on-experimental-any)

```
clang++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test -std=c++1z -stdlib=libc++
clang++ -std=c++1x test.cpp -o test -std=c++1z -stdlib=libc++
clang++ -std=c++1y test.cpp -o test -std=c++1z -stdlib=libc++
clang++ -std=c++1z test.cpp -o test -std=c++1z -stdlib=libc++
```

**But it doesn't compile & complains of the following error:**

```
fatal error: 'experimental/any' file not found
```

`clang++ --version` yields following:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

**How can I get `#include <experimental/any>` to compile?**

**Should I upgrade clang on my machine?**

**Is C++17 supported on clang currently as of today? If yes how can get the support for it?**

Comment: **Is C++17 supported on clang currently as of today?** That header isn't part of C++17, and you say "as of today" but we have no idea how old your Clang is (because Apple give it a stupid version number that has nothing to do with the LLVM release number).

Comment: Is C++17 supported on clang currently as of today? is a question to know **if** I could upgrade my clang to C++ 17 & use `std::any` directly. I guess the answer is no. So how can get `#include <experimental/any>` to compile is the primary question I seeking an answer for. I have update my Xcode to latest running on latest Sierra version. I am unsure if there any ways to explicitly upgrade `clang++` *but what I have should be the latest*. Right ?

Comment: You can answer that for yourself at http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html and http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html but that is for upstream Clang, not whatever Xcode includes. Xcode is unlikely to include the latest, but their weird version numbering makes it hard to know. See Walter's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For OSX 10.12.5 (using Xcode Developer tools), we get

```
> clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

and there is no `any` in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/experimental`, but only

```
chrono
optional    
string_view 
tuple
utility
algorithm
dynarray    
ratio   
system_error    
type_traits
```

So, it appears that Apple's libc++ does not provide `any` (there is no `any` in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/` either). You must either use GCC or your own clang or [`boost/any.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/any.html), all of which you can install via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Answer (score 3):

You misspelt it. It's "experimental", not "experimentals".

However, since Clang 4.0, you should just be using `<any>`.

Comment: I am really sorry for the misspelling. I corrected now :)

Comment: did you mean `#include <any>`. Nope. It doesn't work

Comment: `clang++ --version` does not tell whether its "clang 4.0". How do I get clang 4.0 ?